# Can Processing Implement clippath?

Tags: java, javascript, processing

As you known,we can draw a page showing sin waving by using clippath and continuous changing the d attribute of the path in html,but If I want to implement a clippath with processing in Java?What should I do?walkaround is welcome.

[This page](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/6789) offer by Antonio Molinaro tell the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/6789) solves all your problems. The link is to a Processing applet with the source code for a Strip-Chart simulator. In the first two charts, the demo shows how to plot a sine wave. The code is very well commented. I don't think that posting nearly 200 lines of code (which everybody can download for free under the creative commons license by following the link) would **ADD** anything to this answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: If you had taken the time to follow the link (and don't say you have because it's worse)you would know that on the other side there's only a Processing(Java) applet with it's source code, which I took the time to find for another user at 5 o'clock of the morning, and you would not be bothered by deleting a useful answer. Next time I'll be sure to include e lesson of Trigonometry, too.

Comment: Sorry for my slow response to your answer,since it was weekend in China,I went back to a village to visit my grandma and I have no way to access to the Internet（village in China is not so modern like in other developed country）.I visited the link,the page offer me a great help.thanks.Also sorry for my poor English,I didn`t clarify my   question.